# Attaching to ProjectName

Tags: iphone, xcode4

I am struggling to get my project to build. I have been fiddling with the build settings and now when I run the project it says 'Attaching to ProjectName' and it stays in this stay indefinitely.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

In Xcode navigate to the Product menu and choose EDIT SCHEMES.

In the list on the left choose Run YourAppName.app.  From the Executable menu choose OTHER.

Navigate and choose your .app file in your project directory.

Now run and it works :)