# ios - xCode changes do not appear after creating an Archive

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5

I just created an Archive and now I am trying to add more changes, but for some reason, when I run the emulator, the changes I make do not show up, and the old version of the app runs.

Also, my repository shows the changed files, but for some reason xCode compiles the previous versions of them.

Would anyone know why the predicament I am in might occur?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you change the bundle ID in anyway to make the archive? If you do this xcode will build the app and it will feel like its installing the new one but you're really only seeing a previous version.

You should delete all versions on your phone, do a clean and then run it again to try to fix this unless there is something else going on.

Comment: thanks - how do I check which bundle id I am using? And does it make a new bundle id for me every time? If so, do I need ot switch to it manually?

Comment: and what is the proper way to delete all the previous versions from the code and the emulator?

Comment: The bundle id will be defined in your init.plist(name will vary for your app) file. It won't make a new one every time but the way to delete it off the emulator is just to hold a click on the icon until it gives you the option to delete them. It's the same as a real device.

Comment: the .plist file under the supportingFiles folder? and just delete the entry in the Bundle Identifier field? Now that value is something like com.projname.someotherstuff -- that one?

Comment: Yes that is where it is defined. You don't want to delete that though I was just mentioning that in case it changed. This is the value that uniquely identifies your app.

Comment: I see...sorry but I am still confused about what exactly I should do in order to remove the old build/archive references

Comment: while the emulator is running hit "stop" on xcode to stop the process which should take you to the home screen. The hold a click on the icon of your app or apps that you installed until they shake with the "x" visible and click that to delete them.

Comment: ah got it! Also, one more question..now when I run xCode, it hangs while building saying "Attaching to ProjectName" where it usually shows the build progress bar.  Would you know why that happens?  Thanks!

Comment: This may be the root of your problem then and the solution in this post may be the answer for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186031/attaching-to-projectname