# ios - can not find my ProjectName.app file when I try to edit schemes

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, xcode4

I am having a problem that every time I try to build my project, the build status bar hangs saying "attaching projectName"

So I am trying to follow the instructions here: [Attaching to ProjectName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186031/attaching-to-projectname) and set the project file directly.

But the problem is that I am not finding that directory "supporting files with the file ProjectName.app

That file does show up in my project tree, but for some reason I can not find it on the file system.

Could someone please advise on how to best make sure that the project file is set?

Thanks!

Comment: So which one fixed it, or did you do them all? Inquiring minds want to know :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When really bizarre stuff happens you can:

- shut down Xcode and reopen it, then try again
- remove the "Derived Data" folder for your project (Organizer, Projects Pane)
- remove every folde prefixed with your name inside the project folder (or rename them)
- restart your computer (possibly just logout/log back in)